# SHGetPathFromIDListW Плчему получаю только один символ?

Tags: c++

Нужно получить путь к папке. Использую структуру BROWSEINFO и функцию SHBrowseForFolder(). Но при выводе на экран полученного пути, выводится только первый символ. Как это исправить? Уже замучился искать.

```
//get directory of exe file
BROWSEINFO   bi;
LPITEMIDLIST folder = NULL;
LPMALLOC     shMalloc = NULL;
char         foldername[MAX_PATH];
char         folderpath[MAX_PATH];
string       path;

memset(&bi, 0, sizeof(bi));

CoInitialize(NULL);
SHGetMalloc(&shMalloc);

bi.hwndOwner = NULL;
bi.pidlRoot = NULL;
bi.pszDisplayName = (LPWSTR)foldername;
bi.lpszTitle = L"Выберите папку с базой данных:";
bi.ulFlags = BIF_NEWDIALOGSTYLE;

folder = SHBrowseForFolder(&bi);

if (folder)
{
    SHGetPathFromIDListW(folder, (LPWSTR)folderpath);
    shMalloc->Free(folder);
    shMalloc->Release();

    printf("Folder selected: %s\n", &folderpath);
}
```

Comment: Это не причина ошибки, но тем не менее: `printf("Folder selected: %s\n", &folderpath);` - бессмыслица. Что в аргументе делает этот `&`?

Comment: хорошо, можно и просто cout << folderpath; без разницы

Comment: Вместо устаревшего `SHBrowseForFolder` стоит использовать `IFileOpenDialog` с опцией `FOS_PICKFOLDERS`.

Comment: я пишу в visual studio 2017. как работать с этим типом (или это класс)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема в том, что в коде используются как "широкие функции" (с w в конце), так и обычные (узкие). Широкие символы - это два байта. Если в них хранить символы латинского алфавита, то в отладчике это выглядит как нужные символы с нулевыми байтами. Естестенно, если такую строку попробовать распечатать "узкой" (анси) версией printf, то распечатается только один символ.

Что делать? нужно перейти на однотипные функции. Во первых, вместо char использовать TCHAR, а печатать тогда уже _tprintf

Или явно использовать wchar_t и подобное. Вот минимальная переделка, которая работает

```
//get directory of exe file
BROWSEINFO   bi;
LPITEMIDLIST folder = NULL;
LPMALLOC     shMalloc = NULL;
wchar_t         foldername[MAX_PATH];
wchar_t         folderpath[MAX_PATH];
std::wstring       path;

memset(&bi, 0, sizeof(bi));

CoInitialize(NULL);
SHGetMalloc(&shMalloc);

bi.hwndOwner = NULL;
bi.pidlRoot = NULL;
bi.pszDisplayName = (LPWSTR)foldername;
bi.lpszTitle = L"Выберите папку с базой данных:";
bi.ulFlags = BIF_NEWDIALOGSTYLE;

folder = SHBrowseForFolder(&bi);

if (folder)
{
    SHGetPathFromIDListW(folder, (LPWSTR)folderpath);
    shMalloc->Free(folder);
    shMalloc->Release();

    wprintf(L"Folder selected: %s\n", folderpath);
}
```

Comment: Спасибо огромное!!! Очень помогли

Answer (score 0):

Вызываемые вами функции формируют результирующую строку как "широкую" строку (массив `wchar_t`), а вы затем почему-то печатаете ее как "узкую" строку (массив `char`). Разумеется, напечатается ерунда.

Раз уж вы формируете "широкие" строки, то и печатать их надо как таковые

```
wprintf(L"Folder selected: %s\n", (LPWSTR) folderpath);
```

При этом возникает закономерный вопрос: раз уж вы собрались работать именно с "широкими" строками, то почему у вас все буферы для строк объявлены как состоящие из "узких" `char`? Из-за этого вам приходится замусоривать код явными приведениями к `LPWSTR`, не говоря уже о риске вылета за пределы массива. Зачем? Почему бы сразу не объявить все буферы как состоящие из `wchar_t`? Тогда и приведения к `LPWSTR` станут ненужными.